# History about Triplex Plate Armour?

Tags: military, 15th-century, armour, war-of-the-roses

An example of triplex plate armour was discovered and dated to the War of the Roses at the Royal Armoury of Leeds. They even had a reproduction made by A Plaisance Armouries for a crossbow and musket proofing test, and an Ancient Discoveries [documentary](https://youtu.be/d3yNG8HT6rQ?t=24m56s) talks up the armour the best they can.

I find the technology fascinating and would love to learn more.

Comment: Thank you, CG. Sorry about that, I've fixed the question. I'd love to know more about the history of the armour.

Comment: Looks good now.